# A cuboid is placed in a cylinder. Remaining volume is filled with spheres. Find maximum number of spheres which can fit in.

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

A cuboid whose base is a square of side $4$ inches, and height $6$ inches is placed in a cylinder.

Cylinder has a radius of $2\sqrt{2}$ inches, and height $6$ inches. The gap between cuboid and cylinder is filled with $n$ spheres of radius $0.4$ inches. What can be the maximum value of $n$?

I can figure out that the unoccupied volume will be $48\pi - 96$
and the gap between cylinder and sphere is of approx $0.8$ inches, which means one sphere can be fit in. But how to figure out how many spheres can be there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm showing below how to arrange 14 spheres into each gap. Computing $x$ and $y$ via Pythagoras' theorem is not difficult:
$$
(2+0.4)^2+x^2=(2\sqrt2-0.4)^2,\quad (2x)^2+y^2=0.8^2.
$$
You may check that $y\le0.4$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. First, I mistook your arrangement of spheres for the well-known hexagonal packing. But the hexagonal packing allows only 13 spheres inside the gap in question. When I realized that your arrangement is different, I used a geometrical construction to draw it and convinced myself of your method. Using your equations, I also obtained the following inequality to determine the maximum number of spheres per gap. $$m = \bigg\lfloor\frac{6}{0.8}\bigg\rfloor + \Bigg\lfloor\frac{6-\sqrt{0.8^2-4(2+0.4)^2+4(2\sqrt(2)-0.4)^2}}{0.8}\Bigg\rfloor$$